# detach eventListener from react component

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover, react-component

I have a react component and I would like to call a function when there is an event encountered (onMouseOver). Is it possible to detach the eventListener from the component after its first occurence? (using states would be a solution but I'm wondering if there is another one)

```
handleOnMouseOver = () => {
    console.log('event has occured');
}

render() {
   return(
     <div onMouseOver={this.handleOnMouseOver}>
   );
}
```

Comment: Using a state sounds about right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return a closure, without polluting the state, and keep a flag to disable the listener after the first occurrence.

```
handleOnMouseOver = () => {
  let isActive = true;
  return (evt) => {
    if(isActive) {
       console.log('event has occured');
       isActive = false; // disable listener
    }
}

render() {
  return(
    <div onMouseOver={this.handleOnMouseOver()}>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store a value in your state indicating whether or not your event already occurred.

If it did, you will not return any callback function in your event handler :

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 state = {
  hovered: false
 }

 handleOnMouseOver = () => {
  this.setState({ hovered: true })
  console.log('event has occured');
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div onMouseOver={!this.state.hovered && this.handleOnMouseOver}>AAAA</div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```